# move_uploaded_file is not working in MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I'm running into an issue using move_uploaded_file, specifically that it... doesn't work.
I have an input to upload the pdf:

```
<div>
    Upload Resources
    <input type="text" id="doc-name" name="doc-name">
    <input type="file" id="doc-upload" name="doc-upload" accept="application/pdf">
    <button id="upload-button">Upload</button>
</div>
```

And some jquery that sends a POST request with that file:

```
$("#upload-button").click(function() {
    if ($('#doc-name').val() == '') {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var filename = $('#doc-name').val();
        var uploaded = $('#doc-upload').val().split('\\');
        var path = uploaded[uploaded.length - 1];
        var file = $('#doc-upload').prop('files')[0];

        formData.append("functionCall", "document-upload");
        formData.append("filename", filename);
        formData.append("path", path);
        formData.append("file", file);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/assets/functions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorMessage);
            }
        });
)};
```

This sends to my functions file, which is set up kind of odd (it might actually be standard practice, I've just never seen it like this) in that it's one big switch statement; which case gets run is dependent on the functionCall variable passed in. So here is the function code for that specific case statement:

```
.
.
.
case "doc-upload":

    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    $path = $_POST['path'];
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $uploadQuery = "INSERT INTO uploads (filename, path) VALUES ('$filename', '$path')";
    $upload = mysql_query($uploadQuery);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'test/' . $_FILES['files']['name'])) {
        echo 'yay';
    } else {
        echo 'such is life';
    }
```

Everything above the move_uploaded_file line works great, but I keep getting the 'such is life' line returned, and the transferred file does not show up in 'test/'. I know both the test folder and uploaded file are present thanks to a file_exists check. Any ideas about what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Is the directory where you are trying to move the file writable by the web server user?

Comment: also don't see the form tags

Comment: @Chris Good idea, I just changed the permissions to read & write for all and it still is not working.

Comment: @Fred-ii- There are no form tags, I'm using jQuery to pull the values manually.

Comment: look at the console and use php's error reporting, see if anything comes of it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you! That led to me solving it. I tailed that log and got 'The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in ......', which Google explained was a way of saying that my second parameter in move_uploaded_file is not a valid name. So I checked and... there's a typo. Such is life as a programmer I guess. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're most welcome. Glad to hear it and that error reporting/Google came in for you, *cheers*